# GraphQL Fragments reusable across multiple files

Tags: graphql

Is there a good solution to reuse same GraphQL fragments in multiple .graphql files?

I am trying to have all the fragments in one file, and to use them in multiple queries.

Answer (score 9):

You mean, how to export/import fragment accross files ? I would do it like this

```
fragment MyReusableFragment_MyConnection on MyConnection {
  edges {
    node {
      _id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

And import it :

```
#import "./MyReusableFragment.graphql"

query myQuery on MyConnection {
  ...MyReusableFragment_MyConnection
}
```

and reuse it around other file

```
#import "./MyReusableFragment.graphql"

query myOtherQuery on MyConnection {
  ...MyReusableFragment_MyConnection
}
```